# Textview over imageview works fine in Android Version 5.1.1 but not in older version of android

Tags: android, xml, android-version

My app works well on my android phone but not in older version of android...

**Here is my app looks like running from my phone**

[image]

it seems no problem there but when my app uses an older version of Android, this is the result.

[image]

**My .xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/mediaplayerlayout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/example"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/v_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/image"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/image"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/image"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="THIS IS THE TITLE OF SONGS"
                />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/anchor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:minHeight="180dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/body"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/anchor"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                />




        </RelativeLayout>

    </com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollView>

    <include layout="@layout/gradient_header"
        android:id="@+id/include" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
        app:theme="@style/Toolbar"/>

    // ... Other layout here that not included 
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I fix this problem that will works both higher and older version of android?

Comment: I am not getting what you want to ask and please change your screenshot try without messenger header this time

Answer (score 0):

when you build a project just choose the lowest android then it will work on both

Comment: But I choose API 14 minimum